# which port I use when I want to connect remix to my local quorum network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth, quorum

I want to deploy a smart contract on my local network.
I executed a local node via

```
       PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir ./Node1/new- 
       node-1 
       --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft -- 
       raftport 51001 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22101 -- 
       rpcapi 
       admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3, 
       quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21101 2>>node1.log &
```

I have to use localhost:\127.0.0.1:21101 or 22101?
I want to know the difference betwwen the two ports and what are used for?

An other question if you don't mind: 
When i use the port 21101, it fails to connect and when I consult the node log I find :

```
        Failed RLPx handshake addr=[::1]:42552  conn=inbound    
        err="read tcp [::1]:21102->[::1]:42552:  i/o timeout"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an RPC port number to connect the network.

`For examples: http://localhost:22101`

**Difference between the Raft port and RPC port?**

> Quorum listens on port 50400 by default for the raft transport, but this is configurable with the `--raftport` flag.
> You can start the HTTP JSON-RPC with the `--rpc` flag, to change the default port (8545) `--rpcport <portnumber>` If accessing the RPC from a browser, CORS will need to be enabled with the appropriate domain set. Otherwise, JavaScript calls are limit by the same-origin policy and requests will fail:
>
> `For examples: geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:3000"`
>
> Try to use [http://remix.ethereum.org/](https://remix.ethereum.org/) for connecting local networks (unsecured networks). If Https certificate enabled then, you can use https://remix.ethereum.org/